# Rxjava2 OutOfMemoryError

Tags: out-of-memory, rx-java2

I am getting OutOfMemory error very frequently.

Sample Code:

```
Flowable.fromIterable(req.getAllClaims()).filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .flatMap(data -> {
                ClaimStatusCollector collector = statsCollector.get(data.getName());
                collector.setVehicleHelper(vehicleHelper);
                collector.setMedicalHelper(medicalHelper);
                return Flowable.fromCallable(() -> collector.verifyStatus(data)
                        );
            }, 5)
            .blockingIterable().forEach(data -> {
                claims.add(data.blockingFirst());
            });

VehicleClaimStatusCollector.java 
@Override
public Flowable<Claim> verifyStatus(Claim claim)
{
    return Flowable.create(emitter -> {
        try
        {
            //external http call
            emitter.onNext(claim);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            emitter.onNext(claim);
        }
        emitter.onComplete();
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);

}

MedicalClaimStatusCollector.java 
@Override
public Flowable<Claim> verifyStatus(Claim claim)
{
    return Flowable.create(emitter -> {
        try
        {
            //external http call
            emitter.onNext(claim);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            emitter.onNext(claim);
        }
        emitter.onComplete();
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);

}
```

> RxCachedThreadScheduler-6034" #6994 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ffcab9ce800 nid=0x42d07 runnable [0x0000700109ffd000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)

Its very clear that we are getting socket exception from external http request. I have also set readtimeout in jersey client. All the threads are hanged there and it throws outofmemory error.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
>       at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1587)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:549)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.submit(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:648)
>       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.NewThreadWorker.scheduleActual(NewThreadWorker.java:146)
>       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.IoScheduler$EventLoopWorker.schedule(IoScheduler.java:230)
>       at io.reactivex.Scheduler$Worker.schedule(Scheduler.java:273)
>       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableSubscribeOn.subscribeActual(FlowableSubscribeOn.java:48)
>       at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:13234)
>       at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:13170)
>       at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:13091)

Can someone help me on this?